# Linking static libraries with c++/cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, static-linking

I try to link libraries in my program using firebreath framework.

So I add this code in projectDef.cmake.

```
include_directories(/usr/include/giblib)
include_directories(/usr/include/X11)

add_library(giblib_ptm STATIC IMPORTED) 
set_property(TARGET giblib_ptm PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/lib/libgiblib.a)

add_library(X11_ptm STATIC IMPORTED) 
set_property(TARGET X11_ptm PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.a)

add_library(Imlib_ptm STATIC IMPORTED) 
set_property(TARGET Imlib_ptm PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/lib/libImlib2.a)

target_link_libraries(Printmade2 giblib_ptm X11_ptm Imlib_ptm)
```

Why I add **'include_directories'** is I include header file in my .cpp file.

```
#include <giblib.h>
#include <Xlib.h>
```

After execute **make**, this error message appears.

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.a(OpenDis.o): In function `OutOfMemory':
(.text+0x459): undefined reference to `xcb_disconnect'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.a(OpenDis.o): In function `XOpenDisplay':
(.text+0x8f5): undefined reference to `xcb_get_setup'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.a(OpenDis.o): In function `XOpenDisplay':
(.text+0xedb): undefined reference to `xcb_get_maximum_request_length'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.a(xcb_disp.o): In function `_XConnectXCB':
(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `xcb_parse_display'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.a(xcb_disp.o): In function `_XConnectXCB':
(.text+0x1d7): undefined reference to `xcb_connect_to_display_with_auth_info'
...
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.a(xcb_io.o): In function `poll_for_event':
(.text+0x30e): undefined reference to `xcb_poll_for_event'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.a(xcb_io.o): In function `poll_for_response':
(.text+0x6b4): undefined reference to `xcb_poll_for_reply'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.a(xcb_io.o): In function `_XSend':
(.text+0x85f): undefined reference to `xcb_writev'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.a(xcb_io.o): In function `_XReadEvents':
(.text+0xa1f): undefined reference to `xcb_connection_has_error'
....
```

I think this error is cause by **'add_library'** and **'set_property'**,

but I can't understand why.

What should I do for linking static libraries in my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the creation of a static library.  A static library is a collection of object files, it does not have any init/deinit code to pull in additional libraries like a shared library or an executable can.

If you create a *libraryA* that uses code from *libraryB* and *libraryC* when you build *applicationX* that uses *libraryA* you must manually pull in both *libraryB* and *libraryC*.  With shared libraries this is not necessary.

If you investigate `pkg-config` you can see the property `Libs.private` that specifies these additional *private* or internal libraries that a static link would require.