# Unable to link libCurl.a static library in CMake on Android

Tags: android, cmake, static-libraries, libcurl

I am new to CMake and spent almost 2 weeks searching all over the internet trying to figure out why I am unable to link libcurl static libraries with my cpp sources in Cmake within my android project.

I found this repo: https://github.com/gcesarmza/curl-android-ios that I used to generate my static libraries for libcurl. It has dependencies with openssl and libz ( I dont know what else it's built with)

Here's my cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

include_directories(
    ${EXTERNAL}/libCurl/include/
    #${EXTERNAL}/openssl/include/
)

add_library(
    libcurl
    STATIC IMPORTED SHARED
)

set_target_properties(
    libcurl
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${EXTERNAL}/libcurl/lib/android/libcurl.a
)

add_library(
    libz
    STATIC IMPORTED
)

set_target_properties(
    libz
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${EXTERNAL}/zlib/lib/armeabi-v7a/libz.a
)

set(WHARE_LIBRARY Whare_Native)

add_library(
         ${WHARE_LIBRARY}
         SHARED

         ${CPP_SOURCE}/MyWebRequest.cpp
         )

target_link_libraries(
     ${WHARE_LIBRARY}
     libcurl
     libz
 )
```

I have a simple cpp implementation that makes curl calls such as curl_easy_init(). I am getting the following linker error when I build the project with this CMake file:

```
[9/9] Linking CXX shared library 
../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64- 
v8a/libWhare_Native.so
FAILED: : && /Users/jay.nagar/Library/Android/sdk/ndk- 
bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  -- 
target=aarch64-none-linux-android --gcc- 
.........
.........
.........
.........
WhareWebRequest.cpp:40: undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have spent days on Stackoverflow , GitHub and other sources and also tried many solutions that have been suggested, such as:

[How to use libcurl as a static library with cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464932/how-to-use-libcurl-as-a-static-library-with-cmake)

and

[Linking static libraries with c++/cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087171/linking-static-libraries-with-c-cmake)

I also looked up CMake official documentation to understand the different properties. I experimented with CFLAGS, CURL_LIBRARY, find_library and what not. Like I said, I am a total newbie when it comes to Cmake configurations. Can anyone make sense of the type of error I am getting? I think its related to issues linking with the static libs but I am not sure. Can someone help debug this problem that I am deep into for days!

Thanks and help much appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGORy.jpg[image]

Answer (score 0):

`libcutils.so` is a private system library and is no longer allowed to be linked by app since API level 24.

See this link 
[How to solve UnsatisfiedLinkError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51825635/how-to-solve-unsatisfiedlinkerror/51851842#51851842)

**---- Edit ----**

You need to specify the **correct static lib path** for each Android ABI using **CMake** variable `${ANDROID_ABI}`.

Change below code

```
set_target_properties(
    libcurl
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${EXTERNAL}/libcurl/lib/android/libcurl.a
)
```

to

```
set_target_properties(
    libcurl
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${EXTERNAL}/libcurl/lib/android/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcurl.a
)
```

And ensure that you have all the needed architectures (ABI) of your `libcurl.a`, e.g. `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`, `x86`, `x86_64`

Comment: Not sure if I follow that. I am trying to link libcurl.a (static library that I generated from libcurl sources) with my cpp implementations. I am not sure what libcutils.so has anything to do with that.

Comment: Sorry, i think i see libcurl.a wrongly to libcutils.a

Comment: Just saw a path error on your code, check my edited answer above.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I still get the same linker error. Is there anything else I need to pass into the cmake arguments in my gradle script? Here's how it currently looks like: `
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++14"
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static",
                        "-DCPP_SOURCE=${cppSource}",
                        "-DEXTERNAL=${external}",
                        "-DSANDBOXCPP_SOURCE=${sandboxCppSource}",
                        "-DCMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS=-lcurl"

Comment: Please post your project structure showing how are your static libs organized

Comment: Here's how the directories are structured: 
ProjectRoot
    - AndroidPlugin -- //This is my android project that references libraries from external/
    - external
          - json
          - libcurl
                - android
                       - arm64-v8a/libcurl.a
                       - armeabi-v7a/libcurl.a
                       - include/curl/
                       - x86/libcurl.a
                       - x86_64/libcurl.a
          - openssl
          - zlib
Does this help?

Comment: Where is your project structure?

Comment: I think comments don't retain the formatting. Let me post the project structure as a separate comment.

Comment: You can update your question with your project structure, do include the part how your jni libs are placed

Comment: I just did and for whatever reason, my formatting isn't retaining. I'll see if I can edit it a bit, so you see my structure clearly. Btw, I am not using jni at all. I basically have all of my cpp implementations in a separate shared library (also part of this android plugin project) and these cpp classes are referencing curl static libs. I dont have any java code. So I  didn't think there was a need to configure jni.

Comment: The point you need to take care of is the Android ABI. Specifically, you need to link you arm64-v8a/libcurl.a for your arm64-v8a/xx.so. You should not all the ABI to one same .a

Comment: Btw, still can’t see your updates. I am using mobile phone

Comment: I just added an igmur link to the screenshot. Are you able to see that?

Comment: Make sure your link path is correct for all the corresponding architectures. You can add some “echo” message to check your link paths

Comment: No, when I click on the link, it redirected me to an app download

Comment: Or, to make it simpler, try to only compile and link armeabi-v7a, because your zilb linking path was hard coded to this architecture

Comment: I uploaded the image directly. You should now be able to see it.

Comment: Ok, see it. Try the option I said above. Just try to hard code that ABI and make it out first, then make use of ANDROID_ABI var

Comment: Ensure your paths are reachable, e.g, the EXTERNAL var. maybe you can hard code all the paths first.

Comment: When you mean hardcode the ABI, you mean the entire path hardcoded right? Like this: ${EXTERNAL}/libcurl/lib/android/armeabi-v7a/libcurl.a 
I tried this too but doesn't help :( ... having same exact issue :((. Regarding the libz, I just downloaded it from a random github repo, as I have no idea how to generate those for different ABI. You think the issue might be there?

Comment: Hmm, your understanding about the path is correct. But it looks you don’t have all the sources in hand. But the point is that Android native libs, both .a and .so, are ABI sensitive. They have to compiled and linked with respect to the right ABI dependencies

Comment: It’s midnight for my tiemzone and I need to sleep now, sorry for that

Comment: No worries. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Nope. I just rebuilt the project structure and the make files and now I am getting this error: Build command failed.
Error while executing process 
<path> {--build ../AndroidPlugin/Whare_NativeAndroid/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a --target Whare_Native}
ninja: error: '../../../../../external/libcurl/android/arm64-v8a/libcurl.a', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/libWhare_Native.so', missing and no known rule to make it

Comment: If you want, can share your whole project so that I can investigate further

Comment: Thanks shizen! That won't be necessary though. I tried a few more prebuilt .a files for libCurls on github and one of them just happened to work! So the issue was with the incorrectly generated static libs. Now its all good :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with incorrectly generated libs for the libcurl static libraries. I found some prebuilt .a files here that worked for me: https://github.com/gcesarmza/curl-android-ios/tree/master/prebuilt-with-ssl/android
and 
https://github.com/djp952/prebuilt-libz

It was just pure luck that I found something out of several prebuilt libs that just happened to work. I would be happier if I could generate those myself but in any case, at least I am not blocked :)